# sklearn train_test_split by subject (participant) for a longitudinal (panel) study

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, panel-data, longitudinal

I have a dataset with multiple subjects observed over time. I will be training a sequential model on it, and I need to split it into train/test by *subject* (study participant).

I provided my current workaround as an answer.

---

Example dataset:

```py
from pydataset import data
longitudinal_study = data('Blackmoor')
longitudinal_study.head(10)

   subject    age  exercise    group
1      100   8.00      2.71  patient
2      100  10.00      1.94  patient
3      100  12.00      2.36  patient
4      100  14.00      1.54  patient
5      100  15.92      8.63  patient
6      101   8.00      0.14  patient
7      101  10.00      0.14  patient
8      101  12.00      0.00  patient
9      101  14.00      0.00  patient
10     101  16.67      5.08  patient
```

Expected output:

```py
# Not Implemented
# train_df, test_df = train_test_split(longitudinal_study, by='subject', test_size=0.1)
assert len(set(train_df.subject).intersection(set(test_df.subject)))==0
```

---

I have three questions:

- How to interpret `test_size`? What if number of observations is different for different participants?
- How should stratification by other attributes work?
- **Main question:** What is the best way to split longitudinal data and what tools are available in `scikit-learn` or other libraries?

---

Comment: If I understand the nature of your data, sklearn has a built in splitter object for time series. If you pivot your data to get the ages across columns and one subject per row  then you should be able to use [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)

Comment: @G.Anderson, no, `TimeSeriesSplit` does rather the opposite. Also, if I pivot the data as you suggested, I can use the standard `train_test_split`, I wouldn't need `TimeSeriesSplit`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround one can use the standard `train_test_split` on unique values of the column `subject`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

subjects = longitudinal_study.subject.unique()
subjects_train, subjects_test = train_test_split(subjects, test_size=0.1)
train_df = longitudinal_study[longitudinal_study.subject.isin(subjects_train)]
test_df = longitudinal_study[longitudinal_study.subject.isin(subjects_test)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement your solution by stating that rather than keeping a unique set of `subjects`, it may be better to keep the last observation of each `subject` and stratify on your target (or even a feature).

Both solutions will yield essentially the same result, but stratifying on the last observed period of each `subject` may be important if your data becomes unbalanced with the passing of time.

```py
# Keep last row of each subject
subjects = df.groupby('subject').last().reset_index()
# Split this data stratifying by `group`
subjects_train, subjects_test = train_test_split(subjects['subject'], train_size=0.9, test_size=0.1, stratify=subjects['group'])
```

And then continue as before.

Check [this article](https://danilzherebtsov.medium.com/continuous-data-stratification-c121fc91964b) in case you want to stratify by a continuous column.

Comment: That's generally a great suggestion. With group-by involved you could come up with all various metrics to stratify participants. In the dataset I provided it could be for example average exercise over the lifetime.